# R Loop over multiple interdependent functions failing to loop

Tags: r, loops, google-analytics-api

I am building a function to download Google analytics data from a long list of profiles and need a loop function that can tolerate a profile returning no data.

The problem is that there are several functions needed between the start of the loop and where the error can occur.

The Paste function is pulling an ID from `idsvector` and then the API query is constructed in 2 successive steps. This is then sent to the API using `GetReportData()`. The second ID in the list returns no data from the API. Currently it downloads the data from the first profile, merges it with the master dataset and then stops.

```
    for (v in idsvector){
  view.id <- paste("ga:",v,sep="") #the View ID parameter need to have "ga:" in front of the ID 

  sourcequery.list <- Init(
    start.date = start.date,
    end.date =  end.date,
    dimensions = "ga:channelGrouping,ga:campaign,ga:source,ga:medium,ga:date",
    metrics = "ga:sessions,ga:bounces",
    table.id = view.id,
    max.results = 9999999
  )
}
  ga.sourcequery <- QueryBuilder(sourcequery.list)
                data <-  GetReportData(ga.sourcequery, token)
                error=function(e){dev.off(); return(NULL)}
    if (!is.null(data)) {

      data$Property <- view.id
      final.data<-rbind(sourcequery.data,data)

}
  else {
  next
  }
}
```

How do I adapt this so that it loops back and tries the next ID?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but a better approach for this is to use `lapply`.

It is not clear which library you are using to access GA, so I will make up some code for you:

```
library(data.table)
ga_load_property_data <- function(property) {
  # here goes GA API wrapper magic
}

data <- lapply(properties, ga_load_property_data)
data <- rbindlist(data, idcol = "property")
```

This way you separate the load logic from your iterations.

Comment: Thanks, will play with that. I actually managed to get the original script working with some edits, the script can cope without the "else" if you don't add the extra column.

Comment: RGoogleAnalytics is the package I am using